# typeorm querybuilder: select relation of relation only

Tags: sql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

So I have those entities:

```
Group {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    persons: Person[];
}

Person {
    name: string;
    items: Item[];
}

Item {
    name: string;
    active: boolean;
}
```

**What I have avaible**: an array of group id's `groupIds`.

**My Goal**: To get an array of `Item` but only the one that are containt in a group that `group.id` is within the group array I have and also that have the property `active` `true`.

I tried to build a querybuilder like this:

```
this.groupRepository.createQueryBuilder('group')
                      .innerJoin('group.persons', 'persons')
                      .innerJoinAndSelect('persons.items', 'items')
                      .where({'items.active': true, 'group.id': In(groupIds)})
                      .getMany();
```

But I only get an array of `group` (without any relations) that have a valid `item` in it.

What do I Need to Change, if this is even possible with a single query?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
 this.groupRepository.createQueryBuilder('group')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('group.persons', 'persons')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('persons.items', 'items')
   .where('items.active =:active', {active: true})
   .andWhere('group.id IN (:...groupIds)', {groupIds})       
   .getMany();
```